# Informix CSDK install failing

Tags: java, perl, odbc, informix

I'm trying to install the Informix CSDK to get the drivers for an ODBC connection using Perl and DBD::ODBC.  When running the ./installclientsdk, I'm getting the following error:

```
Initializing InstallShield Wizard........
      Launching InstallShield Wizard........erified.

The wizard cannot continue because of the following error: could not load wizard specified in /wizard.inf (104)
```

I've read that only open-jdk is available on Ubuntu 11.10 so I went and installed the java version, which is where I'm at now.  If I debug, I get:

```
QJMLException: (error code = 3002; message="java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.beans.editors.BoolEditor")
```

I've been following this post:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1483193

But so far no luck on getting JRE running or the CSDK installed.  Any suggestions on this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a JVM included with the software, and the installer should use it if it cannot find an appropriate alternative.  The question then is whether the JVM bundled with CSDK can run on Ubuntu 11.10.  It is certified for Redhat and SuSE, I believe.

Which version of CSDK are you trying to install?  Which kernel version and GNU C Library version are in Ubuntu 11.10?

I'm not keen on the '`...erified`' (as opposed to `...verified`) part of the message; it is ominous when such simple messages are not displaying correctly.

I've not installed Informix on Ubuntu sufficiently recently to have any useful recollections of how well it worked.  I don't remember any problems, but that could just mean I'm old and forgetful.

Comment: Hey Jonathan,  thanks for the reply.  I agree the missing letter didn't make me feel warm and fuzzy either.  The kernel version is 3.0.0-12-generic and GLIBC is listed as (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.13-20ubuntu5) 2.13.  I'm trying to install CSDK 3.50.UC9.  The Perl module I'm using calls the Informix driver from the odbcinst.ini file.  Is it just me or does it seem like a lot of work to extract a driver from the CSDK?  Probably just the pains of learning something new....let me know if you have any suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: Between you, me and the lamppost, the amount of overhead required to install CSDK (in particular, but even IDS itself) is disproportionate to the amount of software installed.  However, Java has to be used for the licencing (IBM rules), so we have to lug along more installer than installee.