# Trying to figure out why the Informix JDBC driver won't install

Tags: jdbc, clojure, informix

While trying to install Informix's JDBC driver, I get this error:

```
java -cp /home/ics/sandbox/jdbc/setup.jar run -console
The wizard cannot continue because of the following error: 
could not load wizard specified in /wizard.inf (104)
```

I have pointed to a newer Java from Sun using:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Pointing to a newer Java and, as IBM/Informix support told me, getting away from OpenJDK should allow the installer to run, but that does not work. I also saw using Sun's or IBM's java elsewhere, when I searched for posts on the specific error. On another Centos System, OpenJDK is installed, and I can install the JDBC driver successfully

I also tried removing tty settings from my environment, which also did not work.
Here is the [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304325/informix-csdk-install-failing) where this error is mentioned.

If anyone has heard of a solution, I'd love to hear it, 'cause without the jdbc driver, there's no Clojure database work with Informix, and, when working, it works well. And, I have thought of tarring and zipping the good install and moving it, but that's kind of cheating.

This problem occurs on

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

The installed java version, not my workaround newer version is

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11.90) (rhel-1.62.1.11.11.90.el6_4-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Here's come a shoot in the dark, but is something what already happen with me. Try open a "clear" session without variables set at your profile and run the installer. In past I already get into this error when I have variables set with TTY colors `blue=$(tput setf 1)` .

Comment: I like Jonathan Leffler comment from so post you mentioned. When I had to install JDBC drivers on various machines I simply install it on my machine, grab 6 jars `ifx*.jar` and copy them to destination environment.

Answer (score 0):

Until an answer arrives that allows an install, I took @Michał Niklas 's suggestion and manually installed the driver under /opt/ on the new system. This worked.

I am still going to pursue the cause of this problem. I edited the OP to reflect @ceinmart 's suggestion to remove tty settings. This did not work, but I found it a useful suggestion.